# Not able to use $http or Vue.http

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

**FOLLOW UP**

A combination of comments answered this question. A followup is why the import/require statements matter. I thought the effectively did the same thing.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I'm trying to use `vue-resource` to make REST calls to an API. I have up to now a working Vue app that also uses `vue-material` and it works nicely. I'm just having trouble getting a reference to the http "object" through which I can make get/post/put calls.

The stack is basically `vue-cli` to create a webpack/npm project. `vue-resouce` is definitely in `package.json`:

```
"vue": "^2.2.1",
"vue-resource": "^1.3.1"
```

`main.js` looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.use(require('vue-material'));
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

import App from './App.vue'

console.log(this.$http);

new Vue({
el: '#app',
//other stuff
});

console.log(this.$http);
```

I put those `console.log` statements because I was initially getting errors like

```
cannot read property 'post' of undefined vue resource
```

Sure enough, both log statements yield "undefined". `Vue.http` yields the same.

What am I doing wrong here? Interestingly, `vue-material` is working fine...

**UPDATE**

Checking inside the Vue instance still yields undefined:

```
mounted: () => {
    console.log(this.$http);
}
```

**UPDATE 2 -- a solution that works**

**Thanks for the comments**, a combination of them solved it. Firstly change the `require` to import:

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);
```

And use the old way of creating a function for `mounted`:

```
mounted: function () {
    console.log(this.$http);
}
```

Comment: Answered this question yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646844/cannot-read-property-post-of-undefined-vue

Answer (score 4):

You need to check for `this.$http` from within a Vue instance method:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.$http);
  }
})
```

Comment: Running just the above code works for me, so there must be something you're leaving out of the code in your question.

Comment: See my comment. There must be some tutorial or something somewhere. But it turned out to be the `import` of `vue-resource`.

Comment: @thanksd thanks, the only thing i left out from this file is data, activated and methods properties - all of which are empty.

Comment: @BertEvans I'm not sure that's the issue here. import vs require both work for me

Comment: @user2393012 what versions of vue and vue-resource are you using?

Comment: He for sure has the `mounted` function definition issue. And agree that either import or require *should* work, but require definitely did not in the other case. Also, with the latest versions it looks like `Vue.use` is no longer required. https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/dist/vue-resource.js#L1544

Comment: oh yeah, @user2393012, the way you're defining `mounted` in your question won't provide a correct `this` reference.

Comment: @thanksd - added versions into main text. BertEvans, thanks, doesn't seem to have fixed it so far though.

Comment: thanks I now have a valid http in mounted - combination of import and changing the function did it for me! I find the import thing really odd. Function thing i understand, i've read about scope before in that case

Comment: this same issue if i try to use `$http` outside the main.js in some service files why ? any idea

Answer (score 0):

You can try an alternative. From the Vue web site:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Real-World-Example-Replacing-Vue-Resource-with-Axios

"Alias `axios` to `Vue.prototype.$http`. Then you’ll be able to use methods like `this.$http.get` in any Vue instance"

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.15.2/axios.js"></script>
<script>
Vue.prototype.$http = axios

...
this.$http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(function(response) {
        vm.users = response.data
      })
...
</script>
```