# Vue-Resource + Typescript: Property 'http' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-resource

I am working with Typescript on a Vue project which uses vue-resource. The project is working fine, but I am getting a typescript compiler error.

[image]
[image]

Notice that I am able to use the module using `this.$http` in my components.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666618/not-able-to-use-http-or-vue-http), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615445/how-to-use-plugins-like-vue-resource-when-using-vue-js-with-typescript), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646844/cannot-read-property-post-of-undefined-vue), answers but none of these helped. Is there a work around for this? Or is there a way to set global options in Vue-Resource with Typescript? Or a way to ignore the error altogether?

**[Edit] Workaround (also attached as my answer):**

One of the workarounds from @Styx 's comment (Github solution is significantly hacky as I refrain from manually making modifications to `vue-resource/types/vue.d.ts`), mentioning here anyway.

Use generics and typecast Vue to any, example `<any>Vue.http`. This however, might result in tslint warning, hence I solved this by using `(Vue as any)` and then access `(Vue as any).http`

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/673#issuecomment-396218657

Comment: @Styx thanks man! Much appreciated! I updated the question.

Comment: I'd recommend to "Answer your own question" instead of editing it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to add a new definition file named 'http.d.ts' where your main.ts is located and the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface VueConstructor {
    http: any;
  }
}
```

This should solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, I got [this](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/673#issuecomment-396218657) link. You can read through, here's a workaround:

Use generics and typecast Vue to any, example `<any>Vue.http`. This however, might result in tslint warning, hence I solved this by using `(Vue as any)` and then access `(Vue as any).http`

Comment: This didn't work for me, the request is never posted.